# Why the scope of aws java sdk is "test" in version 2.X?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the aws java sdk to create clients and access the S3 interface. I can see that there is major rewrite with the 2.X version. However I am not sure why there is a difference in terms of scope in the maven dependency.

I.e. for latest version of 1.x it is as below,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.39</version>
</dependency>
```

and for latest version of 2.X it is,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I understand that the scope as "test" means that it is needed only for unit tests and not needed to build or run.
But is there any catch here with the 2.X version? can this be used for production?

Comment: _Where_ are these declarations?

Comment: in the maven pages - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3/2.17.11 , https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.12.39

Comment: Note that that's not "the Maven pages"; mvnrepository is a third- (or fourth-)party index, and not always 100% reliable. I have no idea why it believes this dependency is intended for tests.